# Why batch searches files only in .bat file directory?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a file search engine in batch but it searching only files in the folred where the .bat file is.
This is full code:

```
@echo off
title Search engine
set path=%HOMEDRIVE%
set filename=\%empty\%
set filextension=\%empty\%
cls
REM echo Under the construction
REM pause
REM call main.bat

:search
cls
echo Where do you want to search? (Leave empty for %HOMEDRIVE%)
set /p path=

:name
cls
echo Whats the name of your file? (Without extension)
set /p filename=
if %filename% == \%empty\% goto :name

:extension
cls
echo What's the extension of your file?
set /p filextension=
if %filextension% == \%empty\% goto :extension
goto :searchingMessage

:searchingMessage
cls
echo Searching %filename%.%filextension% in %path% (This may take a while)
goto :searching

:searching
for /r %path% %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%filename%.%filextension%" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
    echo File found under %p%
) else (
    echo File not found
)
pause
call main.bat
```

Thanks. And I'm sorry if it is something simple. Im new to the batch

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `setlocal` line after `#echo off`. This ensures that variables that have been `set` within your code in one run are not preserved for the next run within the same `cmd` instance.
2. Never change the value of the variable `path`. It is system-defined and contains a semicolon-separated ordered list of the directories searched for an executable if that executable is not found in the current directory.
3. Use the syntax `set "var=value"` for string-assignments. This syntax ensures that any trailing spaces in a `set` command are not appended to the value assigned to the variable.
4. to assign a value of *nothing* (which actually deletes the variable from the environment) use the syntax `set "var="`. The code you have used would set the variable to `\` concatenated with the value of the variable `empty\`. In batch, `%` escapes `%`, not `\` and `^` escapes for other characters that require to be escaped **USUALLY**.
5. `if %var% == something dosomething` would be interpreted as  `if == something dosomething` if `var` is *empty*,  `if %var% == dosomething` if `something` is intended to be *empty* and  `if == dosomething` if both are *empty*; all generating a syntax error since the second string following the `if` is not a comparison-operator like `==`. To detect *empty*, use `if defined var dosomething`, `if not defined var dosomething` or `if defined var (dosomething) else (dosomethingelse)` as appropriate - noting that the string `) else (`, if used, **must** all be on the same physical line.
6. Note that `set /p var=whatever`, or preferably `set /p "var=whatever"` will not *change* `var` if the response is simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It is therefore prudent to execute a `set "var="` on the line before a `set/p`. This characteristic *can* be used to set a default value:

```
    set "var=xyz"
    set /p "var=new value for var [%var%] ^> "
```

which should prompt with `new value for var [xyz] >`  and will retain `xyz` as the value of `var` if the response is simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note here that the `>` is a special character (a redirector) so it's escaped by `^`.

7. Note that if `p` is defined before the `for /r ...` line and no file is found, then `p` will not be assigned by the `for /r`, and will retain its original value. This is especially important in the light of point (1), where `p` may be retained  between runs. BUT - note the possibility to use this characteristic...

```
    set "p=File not found"
    for /r ....
    echo %p%
```

... and please use more expressive variable-names.